# elastic search aggregation and filter in R

Tags: elasticsearch

How do I create a bucket aggregation based on a field value, and then run a query that gives me hits for each bucket (and not each document) with filters?

New in elastic search and I will appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm working my way through this currently.  So far, I've figured out how to aggregate on a field, but haven't been able to apply filters yet.  Please let me know if you've made progress as I see this was posted a while ago...

```
# connect to elastic search
elastic::connect('connection_string',
                 es_port = 9200)

# define aggregation
aggs <- list(
  aggs = list(
    field_name = list(
      terms = list(
        field = "field_name"
      )
    )
  )
)

# search
Search(index = 'index_name', 
       body = aggs,
       asdf = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to apply filter for date as follows:

```
last_week <- query('{
        "range" : {
            "your_date_field" : {
                "gte" : "mondays-date",
                "lt" :  "sundays-date"
            }
        }

}')
```

I used this as the main query. I think you can apply the aggregating to this with the `%search% (last_week + agg)` notation and it should work.